# Set<LocalDate> contains LocalDate best practice

Tags: java-8, set, java-time, localdate

I have:

```
ZoneId gmt = ZoneId.of("GMT");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
LocalDate localDateNow = localDateTime.toLocalDate();

Set<LocalDate> hollidays = new HashSet<>();
```

Can I equal `LocalDate` like this?

```
if(hollidays.contains(localDateNow)){
...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried doing so? :)

Comment: yes and it work. hollidays not empty, I not write how fill it

Comment: So you answered your question, case closed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

If you have a look at `LocalDate::equals()` implementation, you will be able to see:

```
int compareTo0(LocalDate otherDate) {
    int cmp = (year - otherDate.year);
    if (cmp == 0) {
        cmp = (month - otherDate.month);
        if (cmp == 0) {
            cmp = (day - otherDate.day);
        }
    }
    return cmp;
}
```

which looks like a properly implemented `equals` method for dates -  which means it will work properly with `HashSet`s.

An excerpt from the `hashCode()` docs:

> If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result.

Comment: Two equal hashes do not imply that both objects have to be equal. 
There is a possibility that two different dates have the same hashcode.